# Inserting non-printing Unicode control chars in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, unicode

How can I insert a Unicode non-printing character in Google Docs? for example left-to-right-mark LRM Unicode `U+200E`.

I can see a menu option for inserting special characters for Unicode scripts, but it seems to be only for printable chars.

Answer (score 1):

- press <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`I`**</kbd>
- press <kbd>**`C`**</kbd>
- enter in search desired Unicode and then left-click on it to insert it:

  - **`U+061C`** - Arabic Letter Mark
  - **`U+200E`** - Left-to-right Mark
  - **`U+200F`** - Right-to-left Mark
  - **`U+202A`** - Left-to-right Embedding
  - **`U+202B`** - Right-to-left Embedding
  - **`U+202D`** - Left-to-right Override
  - **`U+202E`** - Right-to-left Override
  - **`U+2066`** - Left-to-right Isolate
  - **`U+2067`** - Right-to-left Isolate

[image: 0]